# Calling stream().reduce() on a list with only one element

Tags: java, collections, null, functional-programming, java-8

I am new to functional programming in java, and wonder how I should code to avoid NPE in (for example) this operation:

```
myList.stream()
      .reduce((prev, curr) -> prev.getTimestamp().isAfter(curr.getTimestamp()) ? prev : curr);
      .get().getTimestamp();
```

My intent here is to find the timestamp of the newest object in the list. Suggestions on how to better collect the last element are very welcome, but my main question here is actually why this works.

The documentation says that the function throws a `NullPointerException` "if the result of the reduction is null":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

That is OK, but what I don't quite understand is why I don't get a `NullPointerException` when this code is run with a list containing only one element. I expected `prev` to be null in such a case. I tried debugging, but it just seems to step over the entire lambda expression when there is only one element.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the JavaDoc of [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) says, reduce is equivalent to :

```
 boolean foundAny = false;
 T result = null;
 for (T element : this stream) {
     if (!foundAny) {
         foundAny = true;
         result = element;
     }
     else
         result = accumulator.apply(result, element);
 }
 return foundAny ? Optional.of(result) : Optional.empty();
```

Therefore, if the Stream has a single element, there is only one iteration of the loop, and the single element found in that iteration is returned.

The `BinaryOperator` would only be applied if the `Stream` has at least two elements.

Answer (score 9):

Better:

```
  Optional<Thingie> max = 
      myList.stream()
            .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(comparing(Thingie::getTimeStamp));
```

This overload of `reduce()` returns an Optional; blindly unpacking it with `get` is dangerous, and risks throwing NSEE.  Unpack it with one of the safe operators like `orElse` or `orElseThrow`.

If there's a chance there are nulls in your stream, filter it first with `.filter(t -> t != null)`.

Comment: Thanks. I already check that the stream is not empty, and don't think there could be null elements, but I guess your approach will always be better. I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: That is elegant.

Comment: I think this guy should write a book about java or at least contribute to java source code

Answer (score 3):

NPE will be thrown if the reduce operation actually results in a `null` value.  For example if you try to do `stream.reduce( (a,b) -> null )`.

On another note, to find the newest timestamp, you can do this:

```
myList.stream()
    .map(t -> t.getTimeStamp())
    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder()
    .get();  // will throw an exception if stream is empty
```

Or, with static import and assuming your class is called Thing:

```
myList.stream().map(Thing::getTimeStamp).max(naturalOrder()).get();
```

Comment: Note that this will only return the newest timestamp, and not the object with the newest timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, and the timestamp is what I want.